# io.read is skipped Lua

Tags: input, io, lua

I tried to make a calculator as a good first assignment. Though I'm having an issue the `io.read` function.

Here's my code

```
io.write("let's try making a calculator in LUA!\n\n")

io.write("First number?\n> ")
firstNum = io.read("*n")

io.write("Second number?\n> ")
secNum = io.read("*n")

io.write("Operator?\n>")
op = io.read()

--rest of code goes here--
```

It lets me input `firstNum` and `secNum`, but once it reaches the `op` one it just quits with no error. Here's the output

```
➜ lua test.lua 
let's try making a calculator in LUA!!

First number?
> 10
Second number?
> 20
Operator?
>⏎
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Use `firstNum = tonumber(io.read())` to read a line with a number

Comment: Or `firstnum = io.read( "*n", "*l" )`. A plain `io.read( "*n" )` leaves trailing whitespace in the input buffer (including the newline) so the `io.read()` picks up the rest of the second input line, not the third line as desired.

Answer (score 3):

The cause is, a number is read until you press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. The newline character is still in the input buffer, and is then read by the following `io.read()`.

One option is to read `op` until it's valid. For example, to skip whitespace characters:

```
repeat op = io.read() until op:match "%S"
```

or, to read only one punctuation character:

```
repeat op = io.read() until op:match "%p"
```